# filter and create table

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to create a table from text, but I cannot get the result I want.

this is the text:

> Reading sequence file /scratch/mauve_pro/populations/africa/rebuild_xmfa/block_fasta/africa_final_remove_new.100.fasta

```
NSS:                 1.60e-02  (1000 permutations)
Max Chi^2:           6.20e-02  (1000 permutations)
PHI (Permutation):   5.28e-01  (1000 permutations)
PHI (Normal):        4.73e-01
```

Reading sequence file /scratch/mauve_pro/populations/africa/rebuild_xmfa/block_fasta/africa_final_remove_new.101.fasta

```
NSS:                 8.52e-01  (1000 permutations)
Max Chi^2:           2.20e-02  (1000 permutations)
PHI (Permutation):   3.78e-01  (1000 permutations)
PHI (Normal):        4.53e-01
```

and this is the code:

```
cat africa_final_conca_phi.txt | sed 's/NSS/NSS NA/g' | grep -E "^NSS|^Max|^PHI" | awk '{{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t{genome_stem}\t{single_gene_stem}"}}' > phiresult.tab
```

another code I try:

```
cat africa_final_conca_phi.txt | sed 's/NSS/NSS NA/g' | grep -E "^NSS|^Max|^PHI" | gene=$(printf '%s' "$africa_final_conca_phi.txt" | grep -Eo 'africa_final_remove_new.[0-9][0-9][0-9].fasta') | awk '{{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t gene \t{single_gene_stem}"}}' > phiresult.tab
```

Outcome:

```
NSS NA: 1.60e-02    {genome_stem} 
Max Chi^2:  6.20e-02    {genome_stem}   
PHI (Permutation):  5.28e-01    {genome_stem}   
PHI (Normal):   4.73e-01    {genome_stem}   
NSS NA: 8.52e-01    {genome_stem}
Max Chi^2:  2.20e-02    {genome_stem}   
PHI (Permutation):  3.78e-01    {genome_stem}
PHI (Normal):   4.53e-01    {genome_stem}
NSS NA: 0.00e+00    {genome_stem}
```

what I want:

```
NSS NA: 1.60e-02    africa_final_remove_new.100.fasta 
Max Chi^2:  6.20e-02    africa_final_remove_new.100.fasta
PHI (Permutation):  5.28e-01    africa_final_remove_new.100.fasta   
PHI (Normal):   4.73e-01    africa_final_remove_new.100.fasta
NSS NA: 8.52e-01    africa_final_remove_new.101.fasta
Max Chi^2:  2.20e-02    africa_final_remove_new.101.fasta
PHI (Permutation):  3.78e-01    africa_final_remove_new.101.fasta
PHI (Normal):   4.53e-01    africa_final_remove_new.101.fasta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This oneliner may help:

```
awk '{sub(/[(][^)]*[)]$/,"")}/^NSS/{$1="NSS AN:"}{$(NF+1)=FILENAME}7' *.fasta
```

Let's give it a test:

```
kent$  head *.fasta  
==> 100.fasta <==
NSS:                 1.60e-02  (1000 permutations)
Max Chi^2:           6.20e-02  (1000 permutations)
PHI (Permutation):   5.28e-01  (1000 permutations)
PHI (Normal):        4.73e-01

==> 101.fasta <==
NSS:                 8.52e-01  (1000 permutations)
Max Chi^2:           2.20e-02  (1000 permutations)
PHI (Permutation):   3.78e-01  (1000 permutations)
PHI (Normal):        4.53e-01

kent$  awk  '{sub(/[(][^)]*[)]$/,"")}/^NSS/{$1="NSS AN:"}{$(NF+1)=FILENAME}7' *.fasta
NSS AN: 1.60e-02 100.fasta
Max Chi^2: 6.20e-02 100.fasta
PHI (Permutation): 5.28e-01 100.fasta
PHI (Normal): 4.73e-01 100.fasta
NSS AN: 8.52e-01 101.fasta
Max Chi^2: 2.20e-02 101.fasta
PHI (Permutation): 3.78e-01 101.fasta
PHI (Normal): 4.53e-01 101.fasta
```

Comment: Thanks, it has been a great help

Comment: @AlexGZ pls accept the answer if it solved your problem